# No matching function for call to 'min(uint8_t&, int)'

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to compile some c++ [i2cdevlib code](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU9150/MPU9150_9Axis_MotionApps41.h) with gcc and I'm receiving the error:

```
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/i2cdevlib/Arduino/MPU9150/MPU9150_9Axis_MotionApps41.h: In member function 'uint8_t MPU9150::dmpInitialize()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/i2cdevlib/Arduino/MPU9150/MPU9150_9Axis_MotionApps41.h:605:56: error: no matching function for call to 'min(uint8_t&, int)'
             getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, min(fifoCount, 128)); // safeguard only 128 bytes
                                                        ^
```

Why isn't there a `min(uint8_t&, int)` defined? Isn't this a standard math function?

Am I correct in assuming I'm missing an include or namespace declaration somewhere, and shouldn't define this function myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parameters that you pass to `std::min` is different: one is `uint8_t` and the other is `int`.

The function type of `std::min` is as follows:

```
template< class T > 
const T& min( const T& a, const T& b );
```

You need tell the compiler what's the type parameter of `std::min`.

So the solution is:

```
std::min<int>(fifoCount, 128);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says it all

`error: no matching function for call to 'min(uint8_t&, int)'`

The compiler fails to resolve to the correct specialization as the types of the parameter do not conform (match).

1. Either static upcast the `uint8_t` parameter `fifoCount` to `int` as in `std::min(static_cast<int>(fifoCount), 128)`
2. Or, explicitly specify the type to specialize upon `std::min<int>(fifoCount, 128)`